# PHP : Subreport not displayed in main Report (ireport designer)

Tags: php, jasper-reports

I have one Main Report design with iReport with one (1) subreport whitch
 contain one (1) subreport toow;

I integrated PhpJasperLibrary.

When I call the main report from php file, subreports contents not displayed. What can I do?

How to execute main report and his subreports ?

main.xml

```html
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report_stat" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bbdc1c08-db56-417e-be35-e14e42e720ad">
     <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
     <property name="ireport.x" value="157"/>
     <property name="ireport.y" value="157"/>
     <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
      <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\wamp\\www\\reports\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
     </parameter>
     <queryString>
      <![CDATA[select * from sample]]>
     </queryString>
     <field name="id_sam" class="java.lang.Integer">
      <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
     </field>
     <field name="libel_sam" class="java.lang.String">
      <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
     </field>
     <variable name="libel_sam_1" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page" calculation="DistinctCount">
      <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{libel_sam}]]></variableExpression>
     </variable>
     <background>
      <band splitType="Stretch"/>
     </background>
     <title>
      <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
     </title>
     <pageHeader>
      <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
     </pageHeader>
     <columnHeader>
      <band height="36">
       <staticText>
        <reportElement uuid="44972e96-86d2-40dd-9c3a-2ef3d58983a9" x="0" y="0" width="85" height="36"/>
        <box>
         <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        </box>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
         <font size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Domaines]]></text>
       </staticText>
       <staticText>
        <reportElement uuid="692e1bb5-66c1-4f46-a5e7-02dd35d93676" x="85" y="0" width="100" height="36" backcolor="#C0C0C0"/>
        <box>
         <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        </box>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
         <font size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Savoirs]]></text>
       </staticText>
       <staticText>
        <reportElement uuid="86761251-91ee-4472-b286-9610985a4be2" x="185" y="0" width="115" height="36"/>
        <box>
         <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        </box>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
         <font size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Savoir-faire]]></text>
       </staticText>
       <staticText>
        <reportElement uuid="af7989ad-f1aa-4f3d-ad72-d30566422586" x="300" y="0" width="115" height="36"/>
        <box>
         <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        </box>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
         <font size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Compétences]]></text>
       </staticText>
       <staticText>
        <reportElement uuid="af7989ad-f1aa-4f3d-ad72-d30566422586" x="415" y="0" width="140" height="36"/>
        <box>
         <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        </box>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
         <font size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Appréciation de l'enseignant]]></text>
       </staticText>
       <staticText>
        <reportElement uuid="16b946fa-af0e-44f0-a472-5bfd32ef01e3" x="301" y="18" width="20" height="18"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
         <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[A]]></text>
       </staticText>
       <staticText>
        <reportElement uuid="f98347e3-bdb4-4761-83b9-d7e7461df2a9" x="332" y="18" width="20" height="18"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
         <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[B]]></text>
       </staticText>
       <staticText>
        <reportElement uuid="5bb014a6-3ccf-43b5-8c36-2c5222b46e2b" x="392" y="18" width="20" height="18"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
         <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[D]]></text>
       </staticText>
       <staticText>
        <reportElement uuid="fd6ace43-3901-4623-a71a-58f9fc923fa2" x="361" y="18" width="20" height="18"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
         <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[C]]></text>
       </staticText>
       <line>
        <reportElement uuid="057bf958-3de7-4feb-9f7d-291161a9a1ee" x="301" y="18" width="114" height="1"/>
       </line>
       <line>
        <reportElement uuid="07e2446e-4710-4c62-9bba-c23afe954c31" x="326" y="18" width="1" height="18"/>
       </line>
       <line>
        <reportElement uuid="2e805dd4-5f6d-4a9e-8a26-84680d57e9b2" x="356" y="18" width="1" height="18"/>
       </line>
       <line>
        <reportElement uuid="65fe2ede-c378-487d-946c-f2684cdcd551" x="385" y="18" width="1" height="18"/>
       </line>
      </band>
     </columnHeader>
     <detail>
      <band height="29" splitType="Stretch">
       <textField>
        <reportElement uuid="7fac254c-1c48-4d73-808a-c187fc3824c8" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="85" height="29" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
        <box>
         <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
         <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        </box>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{libel_dom}]]></textFieldExpression>
       </textField>
       <subreport>
        <reportElement uuid="8e1a0b6a-783e-476a-b990-88e9fc94267c" x="85" y="0" width="100" height="29"/>
        <subreportParameter name="ID_DOMAINE">
         <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{id_dom}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
        </subreportParameter>
        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subrep_discipline.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
       </subreport>
       <line>
        <reportElement uuid="30383bf2-8674-44fa-ba87-8cf97d513d41" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="356" y="0" width="1" height="29"/>
       </line>
       <line>
        <reportElement uuid="eb541d7a-b0e7-46ee-9450-7c05d776dbf9" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="385" y="0" width="1" height="29"/>
       </line>
       <line>
        <reportElement uuid="9e2901c5-50d1-4134-85e9-84998f487728" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="415" y="0" width="1" height="29"/>
       </line>
       <line>
        <reportElement uuid="581f293f-42d6-4b04-a952-61fefa9cbc56" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="300" y="0" width="1" height="29"/>
       </line>
       <line>
        <reportElement uuid="7bf10094-4e40-47d5-9eba-abb2c50261bd" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="554" y="0" width="1" height="29"/>
       </line>
       <line>
        <reportElement uuid="ffa96c89-7397-4e15-8e8c-bd11295b4a77" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="326" y="0" width="1" height="29"/>
       </line>
       <line>
        <reportElement uuid="923e4072-0ea0-4f8b-870b-dcacf5ebfb9d" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="415" y="28" width="139" height="1" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
       </line>
      </band>
     </detail>
     <columnFooter>
      <band height="44" splitType="Stretch"/>
     </columnFooter>
     <pageFooter>
      <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
     </pageFooter>
     <summary>
      <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
     </summary>
    </jasperReport>
```